# Conjugate of a nilpotent subgroup

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a group with $H$ being a nilpotent subgroup of $G$. Let $g\in G$. Is is true that $gHg^{-1}$ is nilpotent in $G$?

Comment: Yes of course, because $gHg^{-1} \cong H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f:H\to gHg^{-1}$ defined by $f(h)=ghg^{-1}$ is an isomorphism.  So $gHg^{-1}$ is isomorphic to $H$, and hence nilpotent.